# Swift 5, NSTextField, controlTextDidChange gives compiler error "Method does not override any method from its superclass"

Tags: nstextfield, xcode11, swift5

I need to verify the characters in a `NSTextField` as they are being input.

I've tried every solution proposed by google and I'm now tearing my hair out because `NSTextField` input verification is a standard thing to do, which means that I'm failing to understand something basic.

```
class MyWinController: NSWindowController, NSTextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textField: NSTextField!

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func textField(_ sender: Any) {
        print("MyWinController textField")
    }

    override func controlTextDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("APNewAPStaticWindowController controlTextDidChange")
    }
}
```

The `textField` function works but when I include the `controlTextDidChange` function I get the compiler error: `Method does not override any method from its superclass`.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look a [Formatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/formatter).

Comment: I got the same error, something was changed in API, so it doesn't work anymore. Looking to headers it should but can't understood why it fails.

Comment: I got , by new rules, these methods(controlTextDidChange etc) SHALL not be declared with override specifier